# Google Contacts to Dropdown List

Tags: javascript, php, html, oauth, google-contacts-api

I'm wondering if anyone can help with this. I am using the following code to pull my google contacts using OAuth and it's working fine so far, I get a response in the console log with XML from google that seems very complicated to read to be honest.

My end goal is to be able to populate a HTML form drop down list with the names of contacts from my address book, and attribute the phone number for that contact as a value for the chosen name.

Here's the code, please let me know if you have any ideas!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var clientId = 'ID_HERE';
    var apiKey = 'KEY_HERE';
    var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly';
    $(document).on("click",".googleContactsButton", function(){
        gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
        window.setTimeout(authorize);
    });

    function authorize() {
        gapi.auth.authorize(
            {
                client_id: clientId, 
                scope: scopes, 
                immediate: false
            }, 
            handleAuthorization
        );
    }

    function handleAuthorization(authorizationResult) {
        if (authorizationResult && !authorizationResult.error) {
            $.get(
                "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/thin?alt=json&access_token=" 
                    + authorizationResult.access_token + "&max-results=500&v=3.0",
                function(response){
                    //process the response here
                    console.log(response);
                }
            );
        }
    }
    </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
    <button class="googleContactsButton">Get my contacts</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

So, I've played around for a bit, and this is what I've got so far, which works fine, I get the results listed in as name on one line, then number on the next, then name, and so on..

Problems so far are as follows.

This only returns a limited number of contacts, I believe there's a limit on the response from the API which is 200 or something (I think), how would I go about having it display ALL the contacts that are there?

Also I'm still trying to get it to display in a select box format, allowing me to choose a name, and it would pass the number linked to that name to the form.

Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>People API Quickstart</title>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
</head>
<body>
<p>People API Quickstart</p>

<!--Add buttons to initiate auth sequence and sign out-->
<button id="authorize-button" style="display: none;">Authorize</button>
<button id="signout-button" style="display: none;">Sign Out</button>

<pre id="content"></pre>

<script type="text/javascript">
  // Client ID and API key from the Developer Console
  var CLIENT_ID = 'CLIENT ID.apps.googleusercontent.com';

  // Array of API discovery doc URLs for APIs used by the quickstart
  var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/people/v1/rest"];

  // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
  // included, separated by spaces.
  var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly";

  var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
  var signoutButton = document.getElementById('signout-button');

  /**
   *  On load, called to load the auth2 library and API client library.
   */
  function handleClientLoad() {
    gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
  }

  /**
   *  Initializes the API client library and sets up sign-in state
   *  listeners.
   */
  function initClient() {
    gapi.client.init({
      discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
      clientId: CLIENT_ID,
      scope: SCOPES
    }).then(function () {
      // Listen for sign-in state changes.
      gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

      // Handle the initial sign-in state.
      updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
      authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
      signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
    });
  }

  /**
   *  Called when the signed in status changes, to update the UI
   *  appropriately. After a sign-in, the API is called.
   */
  function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
    if (isSignedIn) {
      authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
      signoutButton.style.display = 'block';
      listConnectionNames();
    } else {
      authorizeButton.style.display = 'block';
      signoutButton.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }

  /**
   *  Sign in the user upon button click.
   */
  function handleAuthClick(event) {
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
  }

  /**
   *  Sign out the user upon button click.
   */
  function handleSignoutClick(event) {
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
  }

  /**
   * Append a pre element to the body containing the given message
   * as its text node. Used to display the results of the API call.
   *
   * @param {string} message Text to be placed in pre element.
   */
  function appendPre(message) {
    var pre = document.getElementById('content');
    var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
    pre.appendChild(textContent);
  }

  /**
   * Print the display name if available for 10 connections.
   */
  function listConnectionNames() {
    gapi.client.people.people.connections.list({
       'resourceName': 'people/me',
       'pageSize': 2000,
       'personFields': 'names,phoneNumbers',
     }).then(function(response) {
      console.log(response)
       var connections = response.result.connections;
       appendPre('<select>');

       if (connections.length > 0) {
         for (i = 0; i < connections.length; i++) {
           var person = connections[i];
           if (person.names && person.names.length > 0) {
             appendPre(person.names[0].displayName)
             appendPre(person.phoneNumbers[0].value)
           } else {
             appendPre("No display name found for connection.");
           }
         }
       } else {
         appendPre('No upcoming events found.');
       }
     });
  }

</script>

<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
  onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
  onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, what is the problem? :)

Comment: @SisterSadie23 I’m very confused regarding parsing the data back from google and picking only the name and phone columns and use them to populate a drop down list in html!

Comment: if you use the console, you can navigate through the `response` and find where the contacts are stored. Then you can do : `var contacts = response.path.to.contacts` and start adding them one-by-one to a drop-down (check for plugins like bootstrap for the drop down). But basically, you've done all the hard part (connecting to GoogleApi) :)

Comment: @SisterSadie23 , I'm doing my best, but I never got involved with parsing XML or JSON, so it's a bit confusing.
I've tried adding the following to the beginning of my php.
   `var firstName = ["0"].gd$name.gd$fullName;`
and then printing that to the console, but it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Accessing the Contacts

When you receive the *response*, the contacts are located under `response.feed.entry`, which is an array of *contacts*. Let's save those under `var contacts = response.feed.entry`. And as an example for what follows, let's take the contact *Jimmy* : `var jimmy = contacts[0]`.

You have several attributes that you can access, like :

- Email : `jimmy.gd$email[0].address`. ( there can be more emails )
- Name : `jimmy.title.$t`.
- Phone : `jimmy.gd$phoneNumber[0].$t`.
- Address : `jimmy.gd$postalAddress[0].$t`.
- Last update made : `jimmy.updated.$t`.

**Warning** : If the field is not set, it will be undefined. You have to first verify that it exists, like so :

```
// Standard way
var name;
if (jimmy.title != undefined) name = jimmy.title.$t
else name = "?? well too bad ??";

// The ninja way
var name = jimmy.title ? jimmy.title.$t : null;
```

### Also

Change your **get url** to `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/**full**/...` as you will get more information on your contacts.

### Populating a drop-down

For simplicity, you could use a `<select>` tag and insert the contacts as `<option>` tags in it. Else, you can also use libraries like **bootstrap** that has cool drop-downs menus.

---

### If your code still doesn't work...

Try this code :

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function auth() {
        var config = {
          'client_id': 'OAUTH_CLIENT_ID',
          'scope': 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds'
        };
        gapi.auth.authorize(config, function() {
          fetch(gapi.auth.getToken());
        });
      }
      function fetch(token) {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json',
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          data: token
        }).done(function(data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
          });
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button onclick="auth();">GET CONTACTS FEED</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/lupeke/6233678)

Comment: Not working. The formatting keeps throwing errors for me. I'm pretty sure it's a misunderstanding from my side. 
Mind you, this is grabbing contact details from google contacts which outputs a jSON file.
I'm so lost o.O

Comment: `...this is grabbing contact details...` **yes**, `which outputs a jSON file` **If you meant a  _JSON Object_, then yes**. I tested it with my own google account and it worked as described. The `response` variable IS the JSON object. I can provide more help, but I need more information on what is not working. :)

Comment: It's now giving the output, but my problem is with parsing through that JSON output and only selecting the fullName and phoneNumber variables, then listing those under the select form tag, so when I pick a name, it would automatically pass it's number on to the POST.

Comment: **Accessing the Contacts**, the first thing in my post.

Comment: This is very interesting. To pull the data, this works the first time where it pops up the google auth window, then after that, if I hit the GET CONTACTS FEED button, it throws out an error.
`Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://example-website.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`